# Проблема с TabLayout, при возвращении на прежний Fragment не срабатывает проверка if (savedInstanceState == null)?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть проблема, когда листаю фрагменты, то при возвращении на первый у меня почему-то Bundle равен null и происходит повторное создание фрагментов.
При повороте экрана всё норм
вот так выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отрывок из main, вызывается в oncreate

```
private void initTab() {
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
    adapter = new TabsFragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    adapter.addFragment(new MainFragmentCreateMenu());
    adapter.addFragment(new MainFragmentWatchProgress());
    adapter.addFragment(new MainFragmentAddProductMenu());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

сам адаптер

```
public class TabsFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private String[] titleFragment;

public TabsFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, AppCompatActivity app) {
    super(fm);
    this.titleFragment = app.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu);
}

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titleFragment[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titleFragment.length;
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);

}
```

}

сам фрагмент

```
public class MainFragmentCreateMenu extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
private FragmentTransaction transaction;
private CreateMenuDate menuDate;
private ViewGroup container;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_menu, container, false);
    this.container = container;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { //тут при возврате в этот фрагмент повторно всё вызывается
        transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        menuDate = new CreateMenuDate();
        transaction.add(R.id.create_menu_main_container, menuDate);

        transaction.add(R.id.create_menu_main_container, new CreateMenuCardViewForItem());

        transaction.commit();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

}